# Extract second tuple element in list of tuples

Tags: scala, dictionary, tuples

I have a Map where each value is a list of Tuples such as:

```
List(('a',1), ('b', 4), ('c', 3)....)
```

what is the most scala-thonic way to change each value is still a LIst but is only the second element of each Tuple

```
List(1,4,3)
```

I have tried

```
myMap.mapValues(x => x._2)
```

And I get

```
error: value _2 is not a member of List[(Char, Integer)]
```

any tips?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
    myMap.mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

The value passed to `mapValues` is a `List[(Char,Integer)]`, so you have to further map that to the second element of the tuple.

Answer (score 8):

Would that work for you?

```
val a = List(('a',1), ('b', 4), ('c', 3))
a.map(_._2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that mapValues() returns a view on myMap. If myMap is mutable and is modified, the corresponding changes will appear in the map returned by mapValues. If you really don't want your original map after the transformation, you may want to use map() instead of mapValues():

```
myMap.map(pair => (pair._1, pair._2.map(_._2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `unzip` which turns a list of tuples into a tuple of lists. It is especially useful if you actually want both values from the tuples.

```
val list = List(('a',1), ('b', 4), ('c', 3))

val (letters, numbers) = list.unzip
// letters: List[Char] = List(a, b, c)
// numbers: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 3)
```